# Procedure Oracle retornar linhas da consulta

Tags: oracle, select, procedure

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE CARRO (
    CD_CARRO INT
    ,DONO    VARCHAR(20) 
    ,MARCA   VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

Os inserts

```
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES (1,'VICENTE','FERRARI');
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES (2,'CARLOS','FUSCA');
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES (3,'MAIZA','DOBLO');
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES (4,'FERNANDA','FUSCA');
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES (5,'BRUNA','FERRARI');
```

Tenho uma consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM carro WHERE marca = 'volks';
```

Gostaria que, a partir de uma procedure, retornar a consulta acima

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_carros (dsmarca VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM carro WHERE marca = dsmarca;
END;
```

Gostaria que retornasse em procedure oracle o resultado como se fosse uma tabela normal

Comment: O que você pode fazer no oracle é retornar um cursor, com o resultado de seu select, ou criar uma função que funcione como uma tabela, caso isso te sirva eu posso postar uma explicação de como fazer

Comment: bom ainda não consegui fazer nenhum dos dois rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No *Oracle* você não pode retornar um `select` diretamente através de uma *procedure*, o que se pode fazer é retornar um cursor na *procedure* ou criar uma *function* e usar ela como se fosse uma tabela.

**Utilizando Function:**

Primeiro é necessário criar seu próprio tipo de retorno com todas as colunas que você deseja retornar

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OUTPUT_CARRO_TYPE
IS OBJECT (
    MARCA VARCHAR(20),
    DONO VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OUTPUT_CARRO
AS TABLE OF OUTPUT_CARRO_TYPE
```

Depois você pode criar sua *Function* utilizando esse tipo de retorno que você acabou de criar.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_carros (dsmarca VARCHAR2)
RETURN OUTPUT_CARRO PIPELINED
IS            
BEGIN
    FOR RECORD_OUTPUT IN (
        SELECT * FROM carro WHERE marca = dsmarca
    )
    LOOP
        PIPE ROW (OUTPUT_CARRO_TYPE(RECORD_OUTPUT.MARCA, RECORD_OUTPUT.DONO));
    END LOOP;                   
END;
```

Você pode utilizar a *Function* da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(fn_carros('BMW'));
```

**Utilizando Procedure e cursor**

Primeiro você cria sua *procedure* com uma variável out que será o seu cursor.

```
create procedure prc_carros (dsmarca VARCHAR2, prc out sys_refcursor)
is
begin
    open prc for SELECT * FROM carro WHERE marca = dsmarca;
end;
```

Para verificar o seu resultado por exemplo você pode utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
var rc refcursor;
execute myproc('BMW', :rc);

print rc;
```

Comment: então ele voltaria uma string somente?

Comment: não ele vai voltar tudo que você quiser, só precisa ajustar o tipo novo que vc criou e na linha `PIPE ROW (OUTPUT_CARRO_TYPE(RECORD_OUTPUT.marca,RECORD_OUTPUT.COL2));` ir adicionando esses campos

Comment: Tentei seguir o exemplo no PL/SQL mas na hora de executar diz que a função está em estado inválido

Comment: esse erro aconteceu quando vc tentou executar o `SELECT * FROM TABLE(fn_carros('BMW'));` ?

Comment: Sim, na hora de chamar a consulta

Comment: entra nessa sala http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56238/room-duvida-93568