# Ler uma Procedure de SGBD em ADVPL

Tags: oracle, pl-sql, advpl

É possível ler uma Procedure de SGBD em ADVPL (linguagem da TOTVS) tratando o retorno de um Cursor ?

Existe algum objeto ?

O banco em questão é Oracle.

```
create or replace PACKAGE abc IS
   TYPE abcCursor IS REF CURSOR;
END;

create or replace PROCEDURE x (p1 IN VARCHAR2,
                               pCursor IN OUT abc.abcCursor)
   IS
BEGIN
  IF PCURSOR%ISOPEN THEN
     CLOSE PCURSOR;
  END IF;
    SELECT * from tabela where chave=p1;
END;
```

No caso chamar a SP x do advpl e ter o Cursor retornado.

Answer (score 3):

No AdvPL existem três formas de executar um Statement em um SGDB através do DBAccess:

- **TCSPEXEC()** -- Para executar stored procedures com um ou mais
  parametros de entrada e/ou saída (O Retorno é uma lista dos
  parametros definidos na Procedure como IN/OUT ou apenas OUT)
- **TCSQLEXEC()** -- Para executar statements de DDL ou DML (Sem retorno de
  dados, apenas Sucesso ou Falha)
- **TCGENQRY()** -- Para executar um SELECT no SGDB (Uma Query, cujo
  retorno seja ou possa ser tratado como um result-set.

A única função que tornaria visível ao AdvPL um result-set seria a `TCGenQry()`, usada em conjunto com a função `DbUseArea()` ou mesmo o comando `USE` ... Porém o DBAccess somente permite abrir um cursor usando a TCGenQry() s a instrução SQL seja iniciada com um SELECT. Una instrução SQL iniciada com "EXECUTE" ,"CALL" ou afins, se executada pela `TCGenQry()`, resulta no erro de execução `"Invalid Select / Query Statement"`.

Já a função `TCSqlExec()` permite a execução de instruções SQL como INSERT, UPDATE, CALL, EXECUTE e afins, porém se a execução gerar um result set, ele não é recuperado no AdvPL.

Se, ao invés de criar uma Stored Procedure, você criar uma *Table Function*, será possível recuperar o retorno pelo AdvPL usando `TCGenQry()`. Para isso, veja o seguinte tópico: [Procedure Oracle retornar linhas da consulta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193568/procedure-oracle-retornar-linhas-da-consulta)

Uma vez usando a alternativa acima, o cursor aberto no AdvPL não possui nenhuma diferença em relação a um result-set obtido com um "Select". Para maiores informações sobre como abrir um result-set em AdvPL, consulte a documentação da função [TCGenQry](http://tdn.totvs.com/display/tec/TCGenQry).

Um cursor no AdvPL através do DBAccess usando a função TCGenQry() é sempre aberto como um cursor *Read-Only* e *Forward-Only* (somente leitura e leitura sequencial) endereçado através do ALIAS usado na abertura como parâmetro para a função `DbUseaArea()`. As colunas da linha atual de retorno são acessadas usando a sintaxe `ALIAS->COLUNA`. Para verificar se o cursor chegou ao final, use a função `EOF()`, e para buscar o próximo resultado do cursor, use a função `DBSKIP()` -- equivale a um *Fetch* no cursor.

#### Referências:

- http://tdn.totvs.com/display/tec/TCGenQry
- http://tdn.totvs.com/display/tec/TCSPExec
- http://tdn.totvs.com/display/tec/TCSQLExec
- http://tdn.totvs.com/display/tec/DBUseArea
- http://tdn.totvs.com/display/tec/Comando+USE
- http://tdn.totvs.com/display/tec/Comando+TCQUERY

Comment: E a manipulação do result set é equivalente ao retorno do cursor? Em nenhum momento de sua resposta eu vi você tratando disso em específico.

Comment: Valeu , vou testar.